# Getting Value From Objects to JSP Page

Tags: java, jsp, object

i have function that create objects using attribut from database. here's the code:

```
private DatabaseManager datman = new DatabaseManager();

public Setting systemDetail(){
    Setting set = new Setting();
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM ms_settings";
        Connection conn;
        conn = datman.logOn();
        Statement statement = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(sql);

        while(result.next()){
            set.setSitename(result.getString("sitename"));
            set.setUrl(result.getString("url"));
            set.setAdmin_email(result.getString("admin_email"));
            set.setContact_email(result.getString("contact_email"));
        }

        result.close();
        statement.close();
    }catch(SQLException e){

    }finally{
        datman.logOff();
    }
    return set;
}
```

then, the object will be placed in some of JSP page let say it's system.jsp, which each attribute from the object will be placed in textbox.

How i can getting the attribute value from object?

example

```
   String url = set.getUrl();
```

then        url will placed into textfield in jsp page.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set the object as an attribute in the request & extract it in the JSP.

Add `request.addAttribute("setting",set);` in your servlet

and then in the JSP, you can use :

```
 <%=((Setting)request.getAttribute("setting")).getUrl()%>
```

Or much better, use EL

```
${requestScope.setting.url}
```

[Lots of Examples](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=request+attribute+in+jsp&oq=request+attrb&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.3515j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)